# Recommended Book for Open Book Exam (Algebraic Topology)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation

This is a very soft question --- I have an upcoming open book exam on Algebraic Topology (includes Fundamental Groups/Homology/ Covering Spaces).

Any recommendations on what books/notes are suitable to bring in? Ideally, some books with examples/worked solutions would be great. What I can do is to go to the library and borrow those books.

I am sure some of the experts here can just go in "empty-handed" and take the exams, however I would like to take advantage of the fact that it is a legally open book exam.

Hope this question is not too out-of-topic! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think bringing a book that you've never opened before (or even just skimmed through a few days before) to an open book exam will be much use -- you will waste a lot of time sifting through the book to find what you need, understand the notation etc.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I still have one month to the exam

Answer (score 1):

I would bring Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) which covers a lot of topics including those that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation